# Why we use the collapsable property for View component in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new to `react native` and learning about the `View` component. I found a property `collapsable` for this `View` component in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#collapsable) but when i use it, it does not do anything. How can i feel that it is working or not. Can please anyone tell why we use this property and how to use it? A little example will be more appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**How you used it?**

> 1. If you made it `true`

So it is obvious you won't see any changes as it is the default value.

---

> 2. If you made it `false`

So still it is possible that you won't see any change. It is just for optimization, that is some view does not have any children, so it just gets silently removed. But let's say you have a document where there are around 100's of conditional rendering

**example:**

```
<View>
{
  this.props.name && <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
}
</View>
```

So, if the name is not defined or false, so `<Text>` will not render, and if the `collapse` is false, so you may see the difference in the performance.